# Highlight texts using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i am pretty new to JavaScript so i would really appreciate it, if someone can help me out, 
Basically i am working with a html page like the one bellow

Now i am only interested in the Level column of the html code, i want my JavaScript or jQuery script to highlight any case's with level 3 in red background color,any sample code or demo would be very helpful :)

EDIT: To be clear i want the script to check all the rows and check if the level is 3 then highlight that specific case with red background color, not when checkbox is checked!, And i do have access to the sever side html files, which is why i am using javascript to do this locally to modify the page like a plugin.

```html
 
<table id="SearchResultsTable" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr class="sr-header"> 
      <th class="tiny bulk-hidden" valign="top" width="3%" align="left"><input id="selectAll" class="bulk-checkbox-header bulk-hidden" onclick="selectAllCases(this.checked);" type="checkbox"> </th>
      <th class="tiny" valign="top" width="5%" align="left"><nobr><a href="" class="tiny-white">Case ID</a> </nobr> </th>
      <th class="tiny" valign="top" width="30%" align="left"><nobr><a href="" class="tiny-white">Subject</a> </nobr> </th>
      <th class="tiny" valign="top" width="20%" align="left"><nobr> </nobr> </th>
      <th class="tiny" valign="top" width="2%" align="left"><nobr><a href="" class="tiny-white">Level</a> </nobr> </th>
      <th class="tiny" valign="top" width="15%" align="left"><nobr><a href="" class="tiny-white">Status</a> </nobr> </th>
      <th class="tiny" valign="top" width="10%" align="left"><nobr> </nobr> </th>
      <th class="tiny" valign="top" width="5%" align="left"><nobr> </nobr> </th>
      <th class="tiny" valign="top" width="5%" align="right"><nobr><strong></strong> <img src="" border="0"></nobr> </th>
      <th class="tiny" valign="top" width="5%" align="right"><nobr> </nobr> </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="sr-light-band">
      <td class="small bulk-hidden" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left">
        <input name="selectCase" id="1696368392-checkbox" class="bulk-checkbox bulk-hidden" value="1696368392" type="checkbox">
      </td>

      <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left"><a>1696368392</a></td>
      <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left">
        <div title="Case1" style="position:relative; overflow:hidden; height:100%">
          <div style="position:absolute; white-space:nowrap">
            <a title="Case1">Case1</a>
          </div>
          &nbsp;
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left">
        <div title="Jussi" style="position:relative; overflow:hidden; height:100%">
          <div style="position:absolute; white-space:nowrap">
          </div>
          &nbsp;
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left">3</td>
      <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left">Unassigned</td>
      <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left"></td>
      <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left"></td>
      <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left"></td>
      <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="right"></td>
      <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sr-dark-band">
      <td class="small bulk-hidden" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left">
        <input name="selectCase" id="1694436342-checkbox" class="bulk-checkbox bulk-hidden" value="1694436342" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left"><a>1694436342</a></td>
      <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left">
        <div title="Case2" style="position:relative; overflow:hidden; height:100%">
          <div style="position:absolute; white-space:nowrap">
            <a title="Case2">Case2</a>
          </div>
          &nbsp;
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left">
        <div title="" style="position:relative; overflow:hidden; height:100%">
          <div style="position:absolute; white-space:nowrap">
            <a href="" title=""></a>
          </div>
          &nbsp;
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left">4</td>
      <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left">Unassigned</td>
      <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left"></td>
      <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left"></td>
      <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left"></td>
      <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="right"></td>
      <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="sr-light-band">
      <td class="small bulk-hidden" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left">
        <input name="selectCase" id="1681523912-checkbox" class="bulk-checkbox bulk-hidden" value="1681523912" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left"><a>1681523912</a></td>
      <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left">
        <div title="Case3"position:absolute; white-space:nowrap">
          <a title="Case3">Case3</a>
        </div>
        &nbsp;
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left">
      <div title="Jussi" style="position:relative; overflow:hidden; height:100%">
        <div style="position:absolute; white-space:nowrap">
        </div>
        &nbsp;
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left">3</td>
    <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left">Unassigned</td>
    <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left"></td>
    <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left"></td>
    <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left"></td>
    <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="right"></td>
    <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="right"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ozarov/3/edit?html,js,output

Comment: with a small modification you could do it only using CSS.
Just put the level value as an attrtibute-value to the td element, then you can use attribute value css selectors.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the code but, i dont want to highlight the text when check box is checked, i want the script to check if the case row has level 3, if yes then highlight it, check box is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var levelColumnIndex = 5;
  $('tr td:nth-child('+levelColumnIndex+')').each(function() {
    var cellText = $(this).html(); 
    if(cellText == 3){
              $(this).parent().css('background-color','red');
    } 
    });
});
```

This should highlight only rows with Level value equals to 3. Of course this solution is based on column index which should be known before. Fortunately jQuery handles nth-child in the absense of native browser support so you shouldn't bother if your browser doesn't support it.

Here is a working demo of my solution [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hobbmnqp/)

Answer (score 0):

You try this..

```
function hiliter(word, element) {
    var rgxp = new RegExp(word, 'g');
    var repl = '<span class="myClass">' + word + '</span>';
    element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(rgxp, repl);
}
hiliter('dolor');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").change(function () {
        alert();
        if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
            $(this).closest('tr').addClass("checked");
        } else $(this).closest('tr').removeClass("checked");
    });
});
```

```css
.checked {
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr id="row_0" role="row" class="odd">
        <td class="sorting_1">
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do this,

1: select the header level postion.
2: search all td value for that position

```js
var levelstatusPosition = "";

$("#SearchResultsTable th").each(function(k,v){ // find the header location of level column
  
  
  if($(v).find("a" ))
  {

     if($.trim($(this).text()) == "Level")
     {
       levelstatusPosition = k + 1; // 0 based
     }
  }
  
  });


$('#SearchResultsTable tr td:nth-child('+levelstatusPosition+')').each(function(k,v){

  if($(v).text() == 3)
  {
    $(v).parent().css("background","red")
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="SearchResultsTable" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr class="sr-header"> 

          <th class="tiny bulk-hidden" valign="top" width="3%" align="left"><input id="selectAll" class="bulk-checkbox-header bulk-hidden" onclick="selectAllCases(this.checked);" type="checkbox"> </th>
          <th class="tiny" valign="top" width="5%" align="left"><nobr><a href="" class="tiny-white">Case ID</a> </nobr> </th>
          <th class="tiny" valign="top" width="30%" align="left"><nobr><a href="" class="tiny-white">Subject</a> </nobr> </th>
          <th class="tiny" valign="top" width="20%" align="left"><nobr> </nobr> </th>
          <th class="tiny" valign="top" width="2%" align="left"><nobr><a href="" class="tiny-white">Level</a> </nobr> </th>
          <th class="tiny" valign="top" width="15%" align="left"><nobr><a href="" class="tiny-white">Status</a> </nobr> </th>
          
          <th class="tiny" valign="top" width="10%" align="left"><nobr> </nobr> </th>
          <th class="tiny" valign="top" width="5%" align="left"><nobr> </nobr> </th>
          <th class="tiny" valign="top" width="5%" align="right"><nobr><strong></strong> <img src="" border="0"></nobr> </th>
          <th class="tiny" valign="top" width="5%" align="right"><nobr> </nobr> </th>

      </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>



                  <tr class="sr-light-band">


              <td class="small bulk-hidden" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left">

              





              <input name="selectCase" id="1696368392-checkbox" class="bulk-checkbox bulk-hidden" value="1696368392" type="checkbox">

              


              </td>


              <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left"><a>1696368392</a></td>


              <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left">


<div title="Case1" style="position:relative; overflow:hidden; height:100%">
  <div style="position:absolute; white-space:nowrap">
    <a title="Case1">Case1</a>
  </div>
  &nbsp;
</div>

</td>


              <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left">


<div title="Jussi" style="position:relative; overflow:hidden; height:100%">
  <div style="position:absolute; white-space:nowrap">
    
  </div>
  &nbsp;
</div>

</td>


              <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left">3</td>


              <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left">Unassigned</td>


              <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left"></td>


              <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left"></td>


              <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left"></td>


              <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="right"></td>


              <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="right"></td>


          </tr>


                  <tr class="sr-dark-band">


              <td class="small bulk-hidden" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left">

              





              <input name="selectCase" id="1694436342-checkbox" class="bulk-checkbox bulk-hidden" value="1694436342" type="checkbox">

              


              </td>


              <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left"><a>1694436342</a></td>


              <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left">


<div title="Case2" style="position:relative; overflow:hidden; height:100%">
  <div style="position:absolute; white-space:nowrap">
    <a title="Case2">Case2</a>
  </div>
  &nbsp;
</div>

</td>


              <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left">


<div title="" style="position:relative; overflow:hidden; height:100%">
  <div style="position:absolute; white-space:nowrap">
    <a href="" title=""></a>
  </div>
  &nbsp;
</div>

</td>


              <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left">4</td>


              <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left">Unassigned</td>


              <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left"></td>


              <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left"></td>


              <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left"></td>


              <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="right"></td>


              <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="right"></td>


          </tr>


                  <tr class="sr-light-band">


              <td class="small bulk-hidden" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left">

              





              <input name="selectCase" id="1681523912-checkbox" class="bulk-checkbox bulk-hidden" value="1681523912" type="checkbox">

              


              </td>


              <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left"><a>1681523912</a></td>


              <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left">


<div title="Case3"position:absolute; white-space:nowrap">
    <a title="Case3">Case3</a>
  </div>
  &nbsp;
</div>

</td>


              <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left">


<div title="Jussi" style="position:relative; overflow:hidden; height:100%">
  <div style="position:absolute; white-space:nowrap">
    
  </div>
  &nbsp;
</div>

</td>


              <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left">3</td>


              <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left">Unassigned</td>


              <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left"></td>


              <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left"></td>


              <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="left"></td>


              <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="right"></td>


              <td class="small" <nobr="" valign="top" align="right"></td>


          </tr>


  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: your welcome , just keep in mind that the accepted answer is valid only till you do not change the order of columns. If you change that you will have to calculate the position, you will have to use this solution in that case.